# нужен код кнопки на css

Tags: html, css

Нужен код кнопки, состоящий из 3 картинок, 1 картинка начало кнопки, 2 картинка дублируется в зависимости от длины кнопки, а 3 картинка завершает кнопку.

Картинки для двух кнопок:

[image: картинки для кнопки]

Стиль кнопки должен получиться такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а скриншот хотя бы показать - вопрос закроют

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Добавил картинку, что я хочу

Comment: Покажите хотя бы целую кнопку, а не набор деталей от конструктора

Comment: ```border-image```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```css
button{
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(#999A9D 50%, #6D6E71 50%) ;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Но все же я так и не понял, зачем Вам танцы с бубном и картинками